# Duda instalación Pi-hole

Tags: bash, instalacion, línea-de-comandos

Alguien que pueda responder a mi pregunta tonta.

Voy a instalar `pi-hole` y me gustaría saber el significado del comando para instalar mediante el método de un paso.

El comando es:

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma rápida, con el comando `curl` te estás descargando lo que hay en el link introducido, en este caso `https://install.pi-hole.net`.

Las opciones añadidas significan lo siguiente:

- `s`: Modo silencioso, es decir, no muestra nada en pantalla
- `S`: Muestra errores, aunque esté activado el modo `-s`
- `L`: Sigue los redirects, para que si una página hace un redirect a otra, esta la siga y no pare la ejecución.

Por último, el pipe (`|`) sirve para pasar el output del comando a la izquierda del pipe (`|`) al comando de la derecha. Básicamente lo que saca el `curl` lo manda al comando `bash`.

Si en el terminal escribes `curl -h`, te muestra la ayuda de todas las opciones que tiene, normalmente tienes esto en todos los comandos, si no otras formas de ver las ayudas serían: `comando -h/--help` o `man curl`, siendo esta segunda más extensa en explicaciones.